# Update pushbutton string using counter when another pushbutton is active

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am setting the handles in the opening function:

```
function Select_A_B_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

handles.output = hObject;
handles.string = '';
new_count = 1;
set(handles.counter,'String',num2str(new_count));
if isempty(varargin)
    varargin{1} = 1;
    varargin{2} = 1;
end
A = {'Apple';'Orange';'Bag';'Cowboy'};
handles.pushbutton1text = A;

new_count = str2double(handles.counter.String);
handles.pushbutton1 = handles.pushbutton1text(new_count);

guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Then I am trying to change the handles to pushbutton1 when the pushbutton tagged as 'Next' is pushed:

```
function next_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

current_count = str2double(get(handles.counter, 'String'));
new_count = current_count+1;
set(handles.counter,'String',new_count);
   set(handles.pushbutton1,'String',get(handles.counter,'string');
    guidata(hObject, handles);
```

I get the following error when I try to set the handles to pushbutton1: 
`Error using set
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.`

I have tried several ways to fix the error, but no success yet. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At what line is the error occuring? My guess would be this command: `handles.pushbutton1 = handles.pushbutton1text(new_count);`. Moreover in the function `next_Callback` you are using `num2str(str2double(get(...)))`...this is useless.

Comment: Moreover, what do you mean by "change the handles to pushbutton1"? I don't understand sorry haha :)

Comment: It is occuring here: ```set(handles.pushbutton1,'String',num2str(str2double(get(handles.counter,'string'))))```

Comment: @Benoit_11 Sorry if I wasn't clear. I am trying to change the value of the cell that is displayed by pushbutton1. So when the Next button is pushed (and the counter goes to 2), pushbutton1 should display 'Orange' rather than 'Apple'.

Comment: I edited the line to: ```set(handles.pushbutton1,'String',get(handles.counter,'string‌​')) ``` and still get the same error. You are correct, the previous version was useless.

Comment: Alright I will write an answer which should simplify things a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a programmatic GUI which does what you want and is, in my opinion, much simpler to understand/debug. You can easily implement this using GUIDE; everything that comes before the pushbutton's callback can be put into the GUI `Opening_Fcn`.

I added comments in the code; if something is unclear please tell me.

```
function DisplayFruits

clear
clc

hFig = figure('Position',[200 200 300 300]);

handles.A = {'Apple';'Orange';'Bag';'Cowboy'};
handles.counter = 1;

%// Counter text
handles.CounterTitle = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[50 200 60 20],'String','Counter');

handles.CounterBox = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[130 200 60 20],'String','1');

%// Content of A
handles.TextTitle = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[50 170 60 20],'String','Content');

handles.TextBox = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[130 170 60 20],'String',handles.A{handles.counter});

%// Pushbutton to increment counter/content
handles.PushButton = uicontrol('Style','push','Position',[130 100 80 40],'String','Update counter','Callback',@(s,e) UpdateCallback);

guidata(hFig,handles);

%// Pushbutton callback
    function UpdateCallback      

        %// Update counter
        handles.counter = handles.counter + 1;

        %// If maximum value possible, set back to 1.
        if handles.counter == numel(handles.A)+1;
            handles.counter = 1;
        end

        %// Update text boxes
        set(handles.CounterBox,'String',num2str(handles.counter));

        set(handles.TextBox,'String',handles.A{handles.counter});

        guidata(hFig,handles);
    end
end
```

Sample screenshot of the GUI:

[image]

As the user presses the button, the counter is incremented and the "content box" is updated.

Hope this helps!

As a side note, I think the error you got above was due to this command:

```
handles.pushbutton1 = handles.pushbutton1text(new_count);
```

here you assigned a string to the pushbutton but later you try to modify its `String` property and Matlab does not like it.

Comment: Thanks, @Benoit_11, you just inspired me to write my first programmatic GUI in Matlab! It is so much cleaner and not too difficult, if you understand what the various commands are doing.

Comment: Yep exactly! At first I wanted to use GUIDE all the times but once you understand how programmatic GUIs work it's not that bad :)